# cassandra and anchor modeling

Tags: cassandra, nosql, anchor, modeling

I would like to go from an anchor model which has only( anchor, knot, tie and attributes) to physical model. i'm working on column oriented database, i'm using cassandra database.

Anyone has any document or any idea that could help me throught this passage ?

Comment: Go through Cassandra DataStax documentation.

Comment: Thanks Gunwant i already read the documentation for apache cassandra and also datastax

Comment: Cassandra is a partitioned row store, not a column oriented database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anchor modeling isn't compatible with data modeling in Cassandra.

Unlike relational databases, tables in Cassandra are denormalised. You start to model your data by identifying all the application queries then design a table for each query so that reads are very fast since there are no foreign lookups and no joins -- all the data you need to satisfy a query are contained within one table.

If you're interested, we have a free hands-on tutorial for Cassandra Data Modeling here -- https://www.datastax.com/dev/modeling. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you @Erick.  i have seen  almost all your tutorial in your youtube channel. You, Alex, Jamie and Patrick and all the team, you are doing a great work which i would like to thank you about.

Comment: Thanks, mate! We appreciate the feedback. Cheers! 